# Floyd Rose Bridge Fine tuner knobs pitch goes up and then down

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning

So i recently got a new guitar which has Floyd Rose tuning system. I had tuned it low when i got it and then went back up to E Standard tuning. Since then i noticed that when i adjust the fine tune knobs, the pitch goes up then down when i let it go. I did raise the bridge up when i tuned it low because the strings were rattling on the frets so lowering the bridge down a bit did help a lot but it is still doing this.

Any ideas of what could be causing this? I saw in videos on how to restring a floyd rose, they recommend to level the bridge with the guitar but doing that makes the bridge float a lot less and stiffens the whammy. And yes, the knobs still make the pitch go up then down when i let go.

Comment: How much does the pitch change when you adjust the fine tuners?  Is it a few cents, or more?

Comment: Almost half step sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i figured out my problem. Its actually quite silly...

The "issue" was simply, i was pressing on the bridge while turning the knob making the bridge bend back a little, lol. So this time i simply was more careful and also followed this guide from Floyd Rose on how to tune the guitars which helped me properly adjust the bridge while tuning.

https://floydrose.com/blogs/tech-talk/string-tuning-instructions

Step 1:
Loosen the three string clamps at the nut

Step 2:
Set your fine tuner screws on the bridge to the middle of their adjustment range.

Step 3:
Tune the strings to your desired pitch (this can be drop tuning, open tuning, or standard pitch, the procedure is the same for any tuning) with an electronic tuner starting with the low ‘E’.

Step 4:
When you have finished tuning all of the strings, check the tuning on the low ‘E’ again. If the low ‘E’ is now flat, re-tune the strings starting again with the low ‘E’ but this time tune the E, A, D, G, and B strings a little bit sharp, then the high ‘E’ to pitch. If the low ‘E’ is sharp, re-tune as just described only tuning the first five strings a little flat. You must tune the strings a little sharp or flat to get to your tuning because every time you change the tension (or pitch) of one string, the other strings change pitch in the opposite direction.

Step 5:
Repeat step 4 until all the strings are at the desired pitch.

Step 6:
When the strings are at the desired pitch, check to see if the bridge base plate is sitting parallel with the top surface of the guitar. If the base plate is tilted forward away from the body, you must tighten the tremolo springs tension by turning the spring claw screws clockwise and repeat step 4. If the base plate is tilted back toward the body, you must loosen the tremolo springs tension by turning the spring claw screws counterclockwise and repeat step 4. [Step 6 only needs to be done on initial setup of the bridge or if you change to another gauge of strings or change to a different tuning.]

Step 7:
When the bridge is sitting parallel to the face of the guitar and the strings are tuned to the desired pitch, re-clamp the three nut clamps and re-tune (if necessary) once again using only the fine tuners.

Step 8:
When tuning is complete, check the action of the strings off the neck. If your action is to high or to low, adjust the action with the two rocker screws (bridge pivot screws) using the 3mm Allen wrench. This adjustment will slightly change your tuning. If your fine tuners run out of range you must repeat steps 1 through 7.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: you can add a stop block that prevents this (and also blocks pull-ups). You can still dive bomb. I used this option because I tend to rest my right hand occasionally on the Floyd Rose bridge.

There's also this option, which allows you to switch between a totally blocked   whammy, the option I described above, or an unblocked whammy: